# Change state from outside Bevy system

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, bevy

i have already have a bevy app that run in the browser.

what i want to do is having some function in the js/ts side that can create or destory a entity in the bevy world, can this be possible? I have try to `let app=App::new();`, then bind a function to run app `app.run();`, and bind a function to override resource `app.insert_resource(...);`. but when i call the function to override resource after run app, it show error with message:  recursive use of an object detected which would lead to unsafe aliasing in rust.
[image]

---

thanks for @kmdreko 's advice, i try to use Arc to update resrouce, but it seems having another problem before this,the problem is after i init the bevy app, the rest code will never reach, there is my code:

```html
<script type="module">
    import init, {BevyApp} from '../pkg/wasm_bevy_demo.js';

    init().then(() => {
        // new() function create and run a bevy app, and return a Arc<Mutex> in BevyApp{}
        const bevyCode = BevyApp.new();
        // this log info never show in the console
        console.log("reach after run bevy app");
        bevyCode.update_scroll_rate(10, 10);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you could probably try modifying the existing resource instead of using `insert_resource` to override it. You'd probably have to use shared mutability though (`Arc<Mutex>` or `Rc<RefCell>`).

Comment: Re your edit, note that `App.Run()` is blocking, see my answer for calling update manually.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the implementation of `run()` function for `Bevy`, when `run()` is executed, the app you created before has been replaced with `empty()`:

```rust
pub fn run(&mut self) {
    // ...
    let mut app = std::mem::replace(self, App::empty());
    let runner = std::mem::replace(&mut app.runner, Box::new(run_once));
    
    (runner)(app);
}
```

So, cannot update bevy app state or resource outside the bevy system.

But, if you still want to update the bevy app more freely, you need to implement your own `runner`. That's what I did in [bevy-in-app](https://github.com/jinleili/bevy-in-app).

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely! A prerequisite is some understanding of [Shared-State Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html).

As you noted we need to tap into some of the capabilities of `wasm-bindgen`, specifically its ability to create a stateful struct, containing an `Arc<Mutex<App>>`.

**Example**

- In this case the `SimplePlugin` just creates a camera and cube with a `Speed` component.
- We are manually calling `Update` because `App.Run()` is blocking and consumes the app. I'm not sure if doing this breaks some `winit` capabilities.

```rs
fn main() {}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Runner {
    app: Arc<Mutex<App>>
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Runner {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Runner {
        core::set_panic_hook();
        let mut app = App::new();
        app.add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
            .add_plugin(SimplePlugin);

        let app_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(app));
        let app_update = Arc::clone(&app_arc);
        let update = Closure::<dyn FnMut()>::new(move || {
            app_update.lock().unwrap().update();
        });

        web_sys::window()
            .unwrap()
            .set_interval_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(
                update.as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
                16,
            );
        update.forget(); //memory leak, use carefully!

        Runner {
            app: Arc::clone(&app_arc)
        }
    }
    pub fn set_speed(&mut self, speed: f32) {
        self.app.lock().unwrap().insert_resource(Speed::new(speed));
    }
}
```

Now we can call `set_speed` from html:

```html
<script type="module">
    import init, { Runner } from './MY_FILE.js'
    init().then(() => {
        var runner = new Runner()
        setInterval(() => {
            runner.set_speed(performance.now() * 0.0001)
        }, 10);
    })
</script>
```